# Bootstrap Multiselect: Clicking button does not drop the dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to build a dropdown multiselect with check boxes using Bootstrap Multiselect. While the button with the carat and nonSelectedText render correctly, if I click the button to get the drop down, nothing happens. The odd part is that if I drop my code into JS Bin or JSFiddle, it works exactly how it needs to. I assume that means it's a css issue, but after several hours of searching, I am coming up with nothing. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" 
                                          type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-
  bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-
       bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-
     multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" 
     type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-
     multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" 
     type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(function () {
        j('#SvcCodeList').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: false,
            nonSelectedText: 'Select up to 3 service codes.',
            numberDisplayed: 3,
            nSelectedText: ' - Too many options selected!'
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Enter Service Code and Dates of Service</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SvcCodeReport">
        <div>
            <label>Service Code</label>
            <select id="SvcCodeList" multiple="multiple" class="form-
                                                                control">
                <option value="1004">1004-Sverice 1</option>
                <option value="1005">1005-Sverice 2</option>
                <option value="1006">1006-Sverice 3</option>
                <option value="1007">1007-Sverice 4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <label>Start Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="datestart" id="start" value=@ViewBag.start 
                                                                          />
        <label>End Date</label>
        <input type="date" name="dateend" id="end" value=@ViewBag.end />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />

    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any error on console? Have you tried loading JavaScript before the end `</body>` tag?

Comment: I'd guess the problem is with your newlines in your library inclusions. I'd recommend loading all of your `<script>` includes on a single line each, and also try refreshing both your JavaScript and CSS cache.

Comment: @ObsidianAge is exactly right

Comment: In fact, the script lines don't have to be one on line, but the issue is carriage returns in the middle of the URLs. Just tested it locally and it works.

Comment: There are no carriage returns in the actual script, that's simply the formatting of StackExchange. I've tested it as well and it tests fine, but I can't get it to work in IIS Express or on the browser after deploying the program.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I disabled the cache in my browser, but the issue persists.